# Define same method in one partial class in two physical files. which will be given priority and why?

Tags: asp.net, oop, partial

I am through a code (written by someone else). Here, what he has done is.

This is a website. I am having a problem understanding how partial classes are working in below case:

There are two pages: 
1. A.aspx  (which has CodeFile A.aspx.cs and it Inherits class B)
2. B.aspx  (which has CodeFile B.aspx.cs and it also Inhertis class B)

Now following is the code structure of both of these files:

Code for File A.aspx.cs

```
public partial class B
{
    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        //Some Code Here
     }
}
```

Code for File B.aspx.cs

```
public partial class B
{
    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        //Some Code Here (but this code is different than that defined in A.aspx.cs)
     }
}
```

In above case, when we load page A.aspx, which code would be given priority?

Comment: Could you please use the real names of the classes, and not A and B?

Comment: Try it. Simplest way to find out (that this will not even compile!)

Comment: Well Oded, I have already written that it is the existing code and it is a running code and problem is I need to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a compile time error when you try to compile this code because you can't define twice the same method

In your case it will raise an error mentioning you already have defined a method with the same name.